# How to use Android mobile as Remote control for wifi enabled raspberry pi car , without using any access point/wifi router

Tags: android-wifi

i want to connect my android mobile with raspberry pi so that i can send some data from pi to mobile through UDP sockets and vice versa. This is because i want to use android screen as remote control , some rPI data display and live video view of pi camera output from android web browser. i am interested to use wifi connection but without using any access point/wireless router in between i.e i want to create a peer to peer wifi adhoc network. in home with access network this will work , but its not possible to have wireless network or carry wireless router where ever the pi go.

for prototyping purpose i tried creating Adhoc wifi network in windows vista but my mobile didnt detect the wifi possibly because the frequency of the wifi network cant be recognised by android. i tried wifi direct feature of my galaxy Note2 (android jelly bean) but i seems to work with only samsung specific phones. it didnt work with nexus 4 neither with windows vista.

so i am quite sure that none of the above technique will work with raspbian OS.

any idea how to achieve my requirements. if connecting raspberry pi with android by USB to microUSB cable will solve the purpose , please let me know how.

Thanks
agoswami

Answer (score 1):

as of now i have used USB/Wifi tethering method which has worked for me.i first tried with USB tethering , it was assigning some IP to Rpi. i changed the /etc/network/interfaces file so that this IP remain static. i used android Ip address as gateway and was able to ping them and even i was able to SSH from connectBot app.

i think the same approah will work for wifi also. i will give it a try later.

this discussion can be closed now :) my issue was resolved.

Comment: Hi can you just give little more information about it, basically what I want is that just connect to Pi from my android phone via Wifi without router. Is it possible. Thanks.